# how to specify values in objects in django: is [] not equal to None?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, if-statement

how can i specify or determine the values in my objects in python if it has this value `[]` or it has `[<Booking: arab>]`,
let us say that in my queryset, i filter a value that not exist in my objects.

here is what i have done : this date_select has no data

```
>>> x = Booking.objects.filter(date_select='2011-12-3')
>>> print x
[]
>>> if x == None:
...  print 'none'
... 
>>>
```

is it `[]` not equal to `None?`
when i try a date_select that has data

```
>>> x = Booking.objects.filter(date_select='2011-12-2')
>>> print x
[<Booking: arab>, <Booking: arab>, <Booking: vvv>]
>>> if x == None:
...  print 'none'
... 
>>>
```

i just want to determine if x has a data or not...
can anyone can give me an idea about my case?

thanks in advance

Comment: Your examples seem to provide absolute proof that `[]` is not equal to  `None`.  Since your examples provide all the proof that's needed, what are you asking, really?   Can you rephrase your question to reflect the fact that you've provided proof that `[]` is not equal to `None`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if your queryset returned any results, call the [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) method.

```
x = Booking.objects.filter(date_select='2011-12-3')
if x.exists():
   # There are some results from this query set
```

If you want to know how many items, you can use [`count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count)

```
x = Booking.objects.filter(date_select='2011-12-3')
print x.count()
```

Answer (score 3):

No, `[]` is not equal to `None`. `[]` is an empty list - a list with no content but that exists nonetheless and can come to have some elements. `None` is a value representing "nothing" - when you find the `None` value, it meas something like "this variable has no relevant content". Since empty lists *can be* relevant content - for example, the empty list can be the initial state of a list which will accumulate elements over time - then there is no sense in assuming that `[] == None`.

armonge gave you the response: just use the list as the condition, because empty lists are "falsy" - that is, empty lists has the same effect of `False` when used as a condition for an `if`,  `while` etc. If you want to execute something when the list does *not* have some content, just negate it:

```
if not x:
    print 'empty list (is not None)'
```

BTW, a question: are you used to program in Lisp? This is the only language where an empty list is equivalent to the "None type" (in this case, `nil`).

Answer (score 2):

You just need

```
if queryset:
    print 'not empty'
```

Comment: thanks for the response armonge, i try your answer but it's not working... can you please suggest me a detail code about it? thanks

Comment: @gadss can you elaborate why is it not working? when you execute your query in the shell is it empty=