# how to specify empty queryset to not empty queryset : [ ] to [<object: hi>]

Tags: python, django

i have a problem in determining an object if it is empty or not...
here is my code :

this value has no data

```
>>> x = Booking.objects.filter(date_select='2011-12-3')
>>> print x
[]
>>> if x == None:
...  print 'none'
... 
>>>
```

this has a data :

```
>>> x = Booking.objects.filter(date_select='2011-12-2')
>>> print x
[<Booking: arab>, <Booking: arab>, <Booking: vvv>]
>>> if x == None:
...  print 'none'
... 
>>>
```

I have learned that `[]` is not equal to `None` from my prev question...
Here is the algorithm that i want to apply in my code:

```
if x has an empty queryset
 print empy
else
 print data
```

can anyone can help me about it?
thanks...

Comment: In the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8365090), the problem probably was that you were using `if x:` to see if the list is empty. However, a non-empty list is _not_ falsy - on the contrary, it is truish, and you would only enter in the `if` if the list was not empty. The simple, quick'n'dirty solution is to negate the list: instead of `if x:` write `if not x:`. However, @Yuji solution below seems far better because more efficient. Just remember to negate the return of exists: `if my_queryset.exists(): print "empty list"`.

Comment: This and the previous question are really just basic Python. Please go and do an introductory Python tutorial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists)

> Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not.
>   This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way
>   possible, but it does execute nearly the same query. This means that
>   calling QuerySet.exists() is faster than bool(some_query_set), but not
>   by a large degree.

```
if my_queryset.exists():
    print "QuerySet has Data"
else:
    print "QuerySet is empty"
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
if not x:
    print "Empty"
else:
    print data`
```

Comment: why -1? (I vote +1 to compensate ...)  Here is selected as solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387727/checking-for-empty-queryset-in-django

Comment: @danihp, I'm guessing because `if ! x` is not valid python (before the edit)

Comment: @YujiTomita, how do you know this? They are a way to see answer before edited? Have you precognition? ;)

Comment: @danihp - you can see edits by clicking on the `edited X hours ago` link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8365278/revisions

Comment: @YujiTomita, thanks. Do you know if is there a way to see deleted answers?

Comment: Yeah, the ! was my bad. Thanks for the +1 compensation.

Comment: @danihp, you can see deleted answers at 10k+ reputation.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
x = Booking.objects.filter(date_select='2011-12-2')
if x.count() == 0:
    print "empty"
```